# Selection Of Ad-Network for Android App

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have following requirement for Ad-Integration.

- **I want My app should be populated only with the Ads created by Me.No other Ads should be supplied-to or feed-to my app.**
- **I would like to do Analysis of Ad I integrated.**

Currently Admob and Inmobi are populating my app with the Ads what they want.
But I don't want to do that.

I have account on both Admob as well as Inmobi.
But I haven't got any option on admin-panel to achieve my requirement.

Can anyone tell In what direction I move ahead to achieve this?or

Can anyone suggest an Ad-network which will suit my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AdMob, you can set up [house ads](https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1619751&topic=1619748&parent=1307209&rd=1) and fully allocate them so that they always get shown in place of network ads.  You'll get reporting on requests, impressions, and cilcks on your house ad campaigns as well.

Comment: Hey Eric is there any Ad-network for video ads which will provide me the facility like House ads(what Admob provides for Banner ads I want it for video ads).
Thanks For your answer I accepted your answer as well as given upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  Unfortunately I'm not sure which network can provide video house ads functionality.

Comment: Have you found any video ad network with house ads functionality?